# Simplexml to database using php

Tags: php, xml, arrays, amazon-web-services, simplexml

I am using amazon api to retrieve a list of actors to store in the database. I keep getting duplicate entries and was hoping someone could help me out if possible.

Here is what I am doing

```
$i = $result->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Actor;
echo "Actor :"; $alist = array(); foreach ($i as $a) {  $alist[] = $a; print_r($alist);  }
```

And he is the result.

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tommy Lee Jones ) ) Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tommy Lee Jones ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => John Goodman ) ) Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tommy Lee Jones ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => John Goodman ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Peter Sarsgaard ) ) Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tommy Lee Jones ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => John Goodman ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Peter Sarsgaard ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Kelly Macdonald ) ) Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tommy Lee Jones ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => John Goodman ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Peter Sarsgaard ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Kelly Macdonald ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Mary Steenburgen ) )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your print_r() function outside of your foreach loop

```
echo "Actor :";
$alist = array();
foreach ($i as $a) {
  $alist[] = $a;
}
print_r($alist);
```

your output grows with each iteration

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tommy Lee Jones ) )
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tommy Lee Jones ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => John Goodman ) )
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tommy Lee Jones ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => John Goodman ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Peter Sarsgaard ) )
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tommy Lee Jones ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => John Goodman ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Peter Sarsgaard ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Kelly Macdonald ) )
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tommy Lee Jones ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => John Goodman ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Peter Sarsgaard ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Kelly Macdonald ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Mary Steenburgen ) )
```

You can find problems easier if you format your code/output better

Answer (score 0):

You could set the name value to the key of the array;
like that a duplicate name will overide the previous key in your array.

```
$alist[$a->name] = $a
```

you have to retrieve the name in string from the SimpleXMLElement Object

I hope i understood your question, and this tips would help

This will remove duplicate entries into your array not the duplicate print_r with shoe the same array with one more row eatch time

Comment: I didn't try this but thanks for your help.